# Post on Facebook Page's wall without having to login (C#)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the following code (which has been posted somewhere on Stackoverflow) to post on Facebook Page's wall.

It works fine, but it opens Facebook Login window if I'm not logged in.
Is it possible to execute the code on behalf of administrator account of particular Facebook Page?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string app_id = "123410186463705";
        string app_secret = "1234ecd9bea862197372de656eb3d7b";

        // using Facebook SDK for .NET
        var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get( "oauth/access_token", new
        {
          client_id = app_id,
          client_secret = app_secret,
          grant_type = "client_credentials",
          scope = "manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream",
          redirect_uri = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
        } );

        var app_token = result.access_token;

        var client = new FacebookClient(app_token);

        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = "Check out this funny article";
        parameters.link = "http://www.natiska.com/article.html";
        parameters.picture = "http://www.natiska.com/dav.png";
        parameters.name = "Article Title";
        parameters.caption = "Caption for the link";

        //446533181408238 is my fan page
        client.Post("/446533181408238/feed", parameters);
    }
```

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426018/generate-never-expire-access-token-for-facebook-page

Comment: Have no idea...But the code above is about 2 years old, it may not work properly any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to use a page access token.

[Generating a Page Access Token.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#generating)

Once you receive a page access token, you can store it as it never expires(if generated through long-lived user token/server side user token). Finally initialize your `FacebookClient` with that token.

A C# specific tutorial is [here](http://www.jamescrowley.co.uk/2011/02/03/posting-to-facebook-page-using-c-sdk-from-offline-app/). The article really old and using the deprecated `offline_access` permission, but atleast you will get the logic right.