# ionic facebook login, Unable to login with openFB, Error in domain url

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, authentication, openfb

i want to login via facebook on ionic app. but it is working fine on browser but in mobile device it fires error as.

```
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. 
To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
 of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

can anybody tell me why this is occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the left hand side of app setting select Products and add product. Then select Facebook Login.

Then add **http://localhost:(Port no)/** to the field 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs', and then everything will work fine.

Comment: by default it is running on port 8100 on development in browser and working fine but in android device it giving this warning.

Comment: Did you put that url in your facebook app setting ?

Comment: yes i did. That's why facebook let me login in my browser.

Comment: check here .. you should take care of url . refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652221/facebook-login-cant-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-a

Comment: getting this error :-
Error
You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this as redirect url

```
http://localhost/callback
```

Comment: Error
You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.

Comment: does anybody have solution of this error
Error
You are not logged in: You are not logged in. Please log in and try again.