# Get a never expire facebook page access token with extended permission to use from rails api only application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, ruby-on-rails-5, facebook-instant-articles

I am trying to integrate `Facebook Instant Articles` to rails api only application. For this facebook provided some end points. Based on their [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api#requirements) to hit that end points i need a never expire page access token with `pages_manage_instant_articles` and `pages_show_list` extended permisions.

But the problem is i am not able to get access token. I followed the following way to get it

**Graph API Explorer**

Using [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) I followed this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426018/generate-never-expire-access-token-for-facebook-page). But when i requested above `pages_manage_instant_articles` permission it is asking me to submit a review to facebook.
To submit that i need to upload a `screen-cast` of app how a user need that permissions. But i don't have any physical app. i am doing this in rails backend application. which screen-cast i can upload here.?

Please guide me how can i get a `page_access` token for this? **or** Explain me if there is any other way.

**Note:** I am trying to do in rails API only application :)

Comment: you don´t need review if you only use the app for yourself. review is only neccessary if you go public with an app.

Comment: but when i try to generate using Graph API Explorer it asking to submit review. @luschn

Comment: not sure what you are doing, but it´s definitely wrong. read this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I am doing exactly like `User Access Token` explained in the above blog. So according to that after i press `Get Access Token` it asking to select extended permissions,  i have chosen those 2 permissions which i explained in question. After that it's asking to submit review :(

Comment: add a screenshot for that please, where it asks you to submit for review. i assume you just misinterpret the "warning".

Answer (score 0):

If you get any warnings during Access Token generation you can pretty much ignore them, I get them when generating User Access Tokens using graph you can also try generating them using the API.