# Facebook token restriction

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

I'm in charge of getting someone's feed page (not a personal page, but a public one like, public figure and so on) in order to fill up a his own personal website. I'm able to get the feed and all the posts, either using the app_id and app_secret using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/posts?access_token=APP-ID|APP-SECRET
```

or creating a token to that page that never expires

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426018/generate-never-expire-access-token-for-facebook-page
```

So far so good. But, just like me, and as far as I know, everyone can create an app and by using it's app_id and app_secret can get the feed as well. Is it anyway possible to restrict this action? Like, only using the token generated by the person in charge of the page (admin), anything able to restrict all other apps/people from getting feed's page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to restrict that for a Page. You can only restrict the Page by age or location, but users with access to the Page can access the feed with a User Token.

Comment: you are welcome, please don´t forget to accept my answer ;)